# Powerpoint VBA code to appear on all new documents

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a macro in Powerpoint 2010 to open a new document based on a template based in a central location, to be installed on several machines.

```
Sub PowerpointTemplate()
Application.Presentations.Open ("file")
End Sub
```

Powerpoint does not save the macro. Even when setting "Macro in:" to "All open presentations", it seems to reset this selection to "Presentation 1". The macro works for the time that I have this current document open, but once I close Powerpoint and reopen it, the macro has been removed.

Is there anyway to set the macro to permanently apply to all presentations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Add-in and load it in order to make the code available to all open presentations.

Setting Macro In to All Open Presentations simply SHOWS you the available public macros in all open presentations; it has no effect on where the macro code is saved.